# Which tool to use to develop toolbar for Internet Explorer and Firefox?

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, firefox-addon, toolbar

I want to develop toolbar for Internet Explorer and Firefox. Is there any common tool? If not, which tool can be used?

Thanks for reading.

Regards,
Sanket

Answer (score 1):

**Firefox:** Firebug, Web Developer

**IE:** [Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en), [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and this crazy new one: **[dynaTrace](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/)**

Comment: Worth noting since the original question doesn't list the version of IE he's developing in, from the Dev Toolbar page:

"The Developer Toolbar is not compatible with Internet Explorer 8.  Please use the developer tools included with Internet Explorer 8.  Press F12 or click the 'Developer Tools' entry in the Tools menu to begin using the tool."

So if you are developing in IE8, you already have this. Definitely helpful for IE6/7 though!

Comment: Dosn't matter: dynaTrace does the job.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Visual Studio to develop a toolbar for IE.  [This site](http://cgeers.wordpress.com/2008/02/16/internet-explorer-toolbar/) gives a detailed walkthrough of the process.

(I believe your question is *how to develop* a toolbar, not *what developer toolbars are available* but please correct me if I'm wrong.)